# Selenium Java - ElementNotInteractableException upon trying to click a link

Tags: java, selenium, click

Within the program I'm trying to make I need to click on links from a variety of websites by searching for links including the word "team". I'm getting an error on a few websites I try it on though, and not on others, any idea why and any fixes available?
My code segment is as follows:

```
if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Team"))
{
     driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Team")).click();      
     return;
}
```

This works on some websites, however on others I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:
```

I don't know the source of this problem however, as I need it to work on multiple pages, for example I get that response on https://www.calipercorp.com/about-us/

Any workarounds or help given would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Team"))
{
     WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Team"));      
     //Check if the element's type is a link
     if (elem.getTagName().equals("a"){
          elem.click();
     }
     return;
}
```

Or you can using the method `getAttribute("href")` to get the link url and then go to this link instead of click on it

```
if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Team"))
    {
         WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Team"));      
         //get the href attr
         String url = elem.getAttribute("href");         
         //add code to go to the url above
    }
```

Comment: I have added another solution, for the first solution it may not correct because some link on web is not clickable. So for the second solution, you will not click on it, you get the url and the go to this url directly

Answer (score 0):

As you want to find a Link with Partial Text. Your approach will be time consuming.

I would suggest to go with xpath as it is easy and less code.

```
//a[contains(text(),'Team')]
```

Sometimes the element's are not visible/clickable. Also sometimes href's are relative. To overcome that go with Javascript click

To check the presence of element use `findElements` don't go with pageSource.

```
List<WebElement> teamEls=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Team')]"));
if(!teamEls.isEmpty())
{
   WebElement team = teamEls.get(0);
   if(team.isDisplayed())
   {
      team.click();
   }
   else
   {
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", team);
   }


}
```